# EOS 'newaccount' action generates the error Error: missing authority.keys (type=key_weight[])

Tags: nodeos, cleos, eosjs, eosio.system

I have created a MultiNode Setup using the Bios Boot sequence https://developers.eos.io/welcome/latest/tutorials/bios-boot-sequence. And created the accounts as 'eosio' & 'accountnum11'. I am trying create accounts using the 'eosjs' package as follows.

```
           const { Api,JsonRpc,RpcError } = require('eosjs');
           const { JsSignatureProvider} = require('eosjs/dist/eosjs-jssig');
           const fetch = require('node-fetch'); // node only; 
           const { TextEncoder,TextDecoder} = require('util');
           const defaultPrivateKey = config.PRIVATE_KEY;

           const signatureProvider = new JsSignatureProvider([defaultPrivateKey]);

           const api = new Api({
                             rpc,
                             signatureProvider,
                             textDecoder: new TextDecoder(),
                             textEncoder: new TextEncoder()
           })


            try {


                const result = await api.transact({
                                   expiration: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 30 * 60000),
                                   ref_block_num: 65981473,
                                   ref_block_prefix: 4183230361,
                                   actions: [{
                                          account: 'eosio',
                                          name: 'newaccount',
                                          authorization: [{
                                                 actor: 'eosio',
                                                 permission: 'active',
                                          }],
                                          data: {
                                                creator: 'eosio',
                                                name: 'test',
                                                owner:{
                                                    threshold: 1,
                                                    keys: [{
                                                       key: myPublic.toString(),
                                                       weight: 1
                                                    }],
                                                    accounts: [],
                                                    waits: []
                                                },
                                                active: {
                                                   threshold: 1,
                                                   key: [{
                                                         keys:myPublic.toString(),
                                                         weight: 1
                                                        }],
                                                   accounts: [],
                                                   waits: []
                                                },
                                            },
                                         },
                                         {
                                             account: 'eosio',
                                             name: 'buyrambytes',
                                             authorization: [{
                                                     actor: 'eosio',
                                                     permission: 'active',
                                             }],
                                             data: {
                                                   payer: 'eosio',
                                                   receiver: 'test',
                                                   bytes: 8192
                                                 },
                                            },
                                            {
                                                account: 'eosio',
                                               name: 'delegatebw',
                                                           authorization: [{
                                                           actor: 'eosio',
                                                           permission: 'active',
                                                       }],
                                             data: {
                                                  from: 'eosio',
                                                  receiver: 'test',
                                                  stake_net_quantity: '0.5000 SYS',
                                                  stake_cpu_quantity: '0.5000 SYS',
                                                 transfer: false,
                                            }
                                          }]
                              })
```

The above operation returns the following error.

```
             Error: missing authority.keys (type=key_weight[])
at Object.serializeStruct [as serialize] (/home/crissi/Documents/EOSS/EOS-APPLICATION/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-serialize.js:597:27)
at Object.serializeStruct [as serialize] (/home/crissi/Documents/EOSS/EOS-APPLICATION/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-serialize.js:590:28)
at Object.exports.serializeActionData (/home/crissi/Documents/EOSS/EOS-APPLICATION/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-serialize.js:1069:12)
at Object.exports.serializeAction (/home/crissi/Documents/EOSS/EOS-APPLICATION/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-serialize.js:1078:23)
at Api.<anonymous> (/home/crissi/Documents/EOSS/EOS-APPLICATION/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-api.js:311:71)
at step (/home/crissi/Documents/EOSS/EOS-APPLICATION/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-api.js:49:23)
at Object.next (/home/crissi/Documents/EOSS/EOS-APPLICATION/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-api.js:30:53)
at fulfilled (/home/crissi/Documents/EOSS/EOS-APPLICATION/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-api.js:21:58)
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:182:7)
```

Any workarounds for the error??

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't define `myPublic` anywhere, and therefore the `keys` field is empty, causing the error. You can get the public key from your private key using the function `getPublicKey` here: https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs/blob/1cf9bf53d21d3f461f61970d3295ee1fc2ba56d1/src/PrivateKey.ts#L55